# Defining primary/partition key for a table with small records

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a table which contains market information at the current instance. The rows in this table will not exceed more than 700. Does it make sense to create primary keys in this instance?

I will be querying this table either to get all the data or search for 'symbol' or 'sector'.

```
CREATE TABLE current(
  symbol text,
  sector text,
  open double,
  high double,
  low double,
  close double,
  volume bigint,
  market_cap double,
  shares double,
  last_update timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (symbol, sector)
)
```

What would be the best approach to ensure quick retrievals?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it makes sense to create a primary key on this table, as cassandra does not allow tables without a primary key. If you have no more than around 700 records in total, I would question the wisdom of using Cassandra for that. Cassandra is designed to efficiently handle billions of records, petabytes of data.

Assuming that you did do a little research before deciding on Cassandra, and still came to the conclusion that it is a good fit for your use case, I also assume that you understood that Cassandra is not a relational database, and that you know about partitioning keys and clustering keys. The partitioning key is hash-based, decides which node(s) in the Cassandra cluster are responsible for handling each row, and will only allow equality lookups. The clustering key is tree-based, decides on the ordering of the rows on a node, and will allow for equality and range lookups.

Also, Cassandra only allows you to do either full table scans or querying on at least the entire partitioning key. So querying on `symbol` **or** `sector` is not feasible without creating a secondary index, which is actually an antipattern, but may not be that bad since you only have 700 rows.

Comment: Thank you for response. I'm using cassandra primarily for timeseries data we collect from stock market. We have a separate table for it which collects upto 300 MB of data daily. This table is updated based latest data added at certain point in time. I'm curious if a small table would be an wise thing to put in there or maybe put it in a separate caching mechanism.